# Is there any way to find the features in sklearn(tree based) on the basis of their significance on the output generated?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am working on a similar Data set as titanic data-set (https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data) and was using tree based algorithms to generate the binary classification output.

```
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
importances = clf.feature_importances_
```

I have used feature_importances_ but this only helped me in choosing right features.

I need something which can tell me the weights or importance of a feature in output generation so that I can provide the end user with tips to improve their result.

Ex:

Name  Age    Math    Science     Hired

X     20      Y         Y          Y

Y     20      N         Y          N

Result should also give Y was not hired as he doesn't know Math (The reason why the binary classification output is "N" along with classifying it as "N").

I went through Sci-kit learn documentation but couldn't find anything which helps me.

Comment: What do you mean by output generation? Which scikit-learn classifier did you use? Why is feature_importances_ not good enough?

Comment: So you need feature importances for each single prediction? If so, google 'model interpretability' and check out the SHAP library.

Comment: in the above example hired is the output (Y) and all the other Name, Age, Math Science (X) after training lets say there is a record which output was predicted as "N". in the response i want something similar

Name has 0 weight, Age have 5 weight, Math have -20 weight, Science have 10 weight and  Hired will get -5 weight  which contributes to Not Hired and I can understand it is because Math(-20).

Comment: Thank yo so much Stergios, This is exactly what I am looking for!